# Generated data for transfer leaning: CNN Not progressing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to produce a simple CNN with data I have generated and have been struggling for a few days now. I simply cannot get it to fit the data at all. After reading online I am assuming there is a data issue somewhere but I cannot find it. I have tried multiple combinations of data manipulation and model changes (more or fewer parameters) with no effect. I am looking at the data going in and it seems fine to me, I've look over it multiple times with nothing unusual coming up.

My outputs for the model are essentially nothing. no increase at all in validation accuracy.

**SOLVED**
See Below

Comment: It doesn't look like you are transfer learning here. Transfer learning is when you load in a pre-trained model on another dataset and allow it to train on your dataset slowly. If your dataset is small, it may be impossible to train a new network on it so I recommend follow this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-using-mobilenet-and-keras-c75daf7ff299

Comment: I ended up deleting most of my code due to no responses but I am generating fake but similar data with thousands of examples, training, and then transfer learning the real smaller dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

For those struggling like I was:

DATA

DATA

DATA

DATA

Better Data, More Data, smaller models, and more training.

I have 1000 real data examples but I generated 30k fake examples. After training on the fake example transfer learning gave me an immediate 87% accuracy.

Overall I highly recommend this method if you have little data and custom problems that you cannot find premade models for.

Check out my generated and real data below.

[image]
[image]